# Error Code: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: k <= n is not TRUE

Tags: r, zoo

I am having an issue trying to figure out an error in my data and I was hoping someone would have some insight.  The error code is:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: k <= n is not TRUE
```

I can get it to work on small data sets, and even subsets of my data.  The error is occurring once every 370-380 rows.  The pattern I see is that it is a "Week 1" in the data and it is only once a year.

Here is a link to the data in .csv form:

http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflowdata

And here is the code I am using:

```
    i = 3
QBrollavgDT <- data.table(rankDT)
QBrollavgDT <- QBrollavgDT[, c("Player_Name", "Season", "Week", "FDP")]
#QBrollavgDT <- subset(QBrollavgDT, Player_Name == "K.Collins")                 <- This works
#QBrollavgDT <- QBrollavgDT[c(381,759,1140,1510,1888,2264.2641), ]              <- these are the rows that thorw the error

        #begin calculating the rolling average and eliminating players with < i games played

        QBrollavgDT <- setDT(QBrollavgDT)[, if (.N >= i) .SD, by = Player_Name] #this eliminates all players with < i games played
        QBrollavgDT <- QBrollavgDT %>% #this is the code that puts the rolling average on and names the column RollAvg
                arrange(Player_Name, Season, Week) %>% 
                group_by(Player_Name, Season) %>% 
                mutate(RollAvg = zoo::rollapply(FDP, i, mean, by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA))
```

It must be related to the week and season, but I don't understand how. I tried every solution I could find, but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: where does `rankDT` come from? Is that read from the CSV file in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs because you don't have enough observations to apply function.

In `rollaply` you specify width as `i` (`3`) and some of your `Player_Name & Season` combinations doesn't have `i` observations. For example:

```
library(data.table)
i <- 3

# Generate data
QBrollavgDT <- fread("stackoverflowdata.csv")
d <- QBrollavgDT[, if (.N >= i) .SD, by = Player_Name][order(Week)]

# Produces OPs error
d[, zoo::rollapply(FDP, i, mean, by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA), .(Player_Name, Season)]

# Subset data where Player_Name & Season combinations have >= i observations
d2 <- d[, .N, .(Player_Name, Season)][N >= i]
d3 <- merge(d, d2)
# Apply rollaply on subseted data
d3[, zoo::rollapply(FDP, i, mean, by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA), .(Player_Name, Season)]

# Result
         Player_Name Season        V1
   1:       A.Dalton   2011        NA
   2:       A.Dalton   2011        NA
   3:       A.Dalton   2011 11.200000
   4:       A.Dalton   2011 15.826667
   5:       A.Dalton   2011 13.353333
  ---                                
2884: Z.Mettenberger   2014 11.220000
2885: Z.Mettenberger   2015        NA
2886: Z.Mettenberger   2015        NA
2887: Z.Mettenberger   2015  9.833333
2888: Z.Mettenberger   2015 10.126667
```

Quick solution:
Calculate `SD` not only by `Player_Name`, but also by `Season`

```
d <- QBrollavgDT[, if (.N >= i) .SD, .(Season, Player_Name)][order(Week)]
d[, zoo::rollapply(FDP, i, mean, by = 1, align = "right", fill = NA), .(Player_Name, Season)]
```

Comment: In a dplyry style, `summarize(QBrollavgDT,n=n())` will show the number in each group.

Comment: Thanks.  I must have just gotten lucky my other data didn't have that issue.  Based on your suggestion I was able to just modify my code as well on this line, where I added season to my `by=` line
`QBrollavgDT <- setDT(QBrollavgDT)[, if (.N >= i) .SD, by = list(Player_Name, Season)]`

Comment: Note that you can pad the input on the left to ensure that it always has at least 3 elements: `x <- 5:6; rollapplyr(c(NA, NA, x), 3, mean)` or if partial means are OK you can use `partial = TRUE`:  `rollapplyr(x, 3, mean, partial = TRUE)`.  The development version of zoo allows short inputs and outputs NAs for them rather than raising an error.

Comment: @runnin4tay5000 you can accept my solution if it helped to solve your problem